# Webservice method not getting the value for the first click

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, web-services

in this i am getting the value through webservice. it's getting the value perfectly. for testing i used print statement and it's showing prefect values, but when i am assigning those values to variable it's not assgning on second click my variable are getting the values.. first time it goes in else, however it should go in if.

```
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {(data, response, error) in
            if error != nil
            {
                print("Error")
            }

            else
            {
                if let content = data
                {
                    do
                    {
                        let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary




                                let asd = myJson.value(forKey: "signinResult")
                                print(asd!)
                                self.answer = String(describing: asd!)
                                var mystring =  self.answer.components(separatedBy:"\"")

                                var mystrin = [String]()
                                let size = mystring.count
                                var i = 0
                                while (i < size-1 )
                                {
                                    let st1 = mystring[i+1]

                                    mystrin =  st1.components(separatedBy:",")
                                    self.em = mystrin[0]
                                    print(self.em)
                                    self.pw = mystrin[1]
                                    print(self.pw)
                                    self.na = mystrin[2]
                                    print(self.na)
                                    self.num = mystrin[3]
                                    print (self.num)
                                    i += 2

                                }


                    }

                    catch
                    {

                    }

                }



            }

        task.resume()

        if email.text == em && pwd.text == pw
        {
            GlobalVariable.myString=em
            GlobalVariable.name=na
            GlobalVariable.number=num
            GlobalVariable.pwd = pw
            GlobalVariable.i=1

            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: nil)


        }
        else
        {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Wrong Email and password", preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert,animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

Comment: what is em, pw ?? is they nsstring ?

Comment: yes these are the string type variables.

Comment: How did you declare that?

Comment: It's because the call is async. Since you print values, you'll notice that it will print AFTER you do `if email.text == em && pwd.text == pw`.

Comment: @Larme can u please explain it? and implement that function, which you are calling async

Comment: @AbhishekMitra var em:String = ""

Answer (score 0):

You set value of that variable in web service block but using it outside the block so first time it doesn't have value to show when you click send time meanwhile web service response and value assign to that variable so get it.

The code should be like this.

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {(data, response, error) in
            if error != nil
            {
                print("Error")
            }

            else
            {
                if let content = data
                {
                    do
                    {
                        let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary




                                let asd = myJson.value(forKey: "signinResult")
                                print(asd!)
                                self.answer = String(describing: asd!)
                                var mystring =  self.answer.components(separatedBy:"\"")

                                var mystrin = [String]()
                                let size = mystring.count
                                var i = 0
                                while (i < size-1 )
                                {
                                    let st1 = mystring[i+1]

                                    mystrin =  st1.components(separatedBy:",")
                                    self.em = mystrin[0]
                                    print(self.em)
                                    self.pw = mystrin[1]
                                    print(self.pw)
                                    self.na = mystrin[2]
                                    print(self.na)
                                    self.num = mystrin[3]
                                    print (self.num)
                                    i += 2

                                }
 if email.text == em && pwd.text == pw
        {
            GlobalVariable.myString=em
            GlobalVariable.name=na
            GlobalVariable.number=num
            GlobalVariable.pwd = pw
            GlobalVariable.i=1

            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: nil)


        }
        else
        {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Wrong Email and password", preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert,animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

                    }

                    catch
                    {

                    }

                }



            }

        task.resume()
```

Comment: can anyone please tell me where i can put the dispatch function for webservice for assigning the value to variable